# No Internet. Missing source list after installation with DVD

Tags: debian

I am running an Acer laptop with Debian 9 64-bit. After I installed with the DVD, there is no Internet connection. I went to my source list to add sources and nothing was there. I added some sources but when I tried to update here is what I get. I will appreciate any help. If you guys need me to post any additional info please let me know.

[image: When I try to update source list]

[image]

Comment: Please use correct punctuation and capitalize your "I"'s. Whenever text is available, it is always preferred compared to screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the commented out lines (the ones starting with `#`) in your `sources.list` file and replace it with these:

```
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free 
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free 

deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free  

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

You can omit the `deb-source` lines if you don't plan on downloading the source code (to compile it yourself).

I just had to do the same thing an hour ago as my wireless card wasn't recognized in the base install and I didn't feel like going into the other room to plug into the router until after the OS was built, so it didn't add any sources. FYI the `contrib nonfree` at the end is so you can install proprietary software like Nvidia or Broadcom kernel modules.

You can read about it [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list) on Debian's wiki.

Comment: Security only has main, not contrib or non-free.

Comment: thank you all for your help i solve this issue thank so much my old acer laptop is back and running thank you everyone this thread is solve

Comment: @arochester that is straight off of the Debian wiki, if you follow that link they include contrib and nonfree. I merely pasted the info here from there.

Comment: @freefix would you be so kind to mark the answer as accepted?